# Adding multiple regression lines to a line plot R

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression

This is the linear model I'm using:

```
blk.lm <- lm(formula = YEARS ~ AGE + AGE2, data = BLKFRIDAY)
```

I want to create a plot with ggplot2 that compares `YEARS` in terms of `AGE` to `YEARS` in terms of `AGE2`, where `AGE2` is just `AGE^2`. My goal is to see whether a linear model or quadratic model is best-fit for my data.

How do I set up a plot where there are two regression lines in terms of `Y ~ X1` and then `Y ~ X2` to compare?

Comment: Can you post a sample of your `BLKFRIDAY` data or share where it is from?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with the `diamonds` dataset from `ggplot2`:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = carat, y =  price)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(formula = y ~ x, se = FALSE, method = "lm") +
  geom_smooth(formula = y ~ I(x^2), se = FALSE, method = "lm", color = "red")
# I(x^2) is needed because x^2 is interpreted as x * X - the interaction of x with x
```

[image]

Note that the red line is curved since it is nonlinear with respect to `carat`.